# The linearity of the extended code

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, coding-theory

If we add a last digit to the code $C$ of length $n$, we obtain a new code called extended code. My question is:

> If the code $C$ is linear, can we prove that the extended code $C'$ is linear too?

Comment: With respect to the edit, "last digit" implies add it onto the end, "extra digit" does not. Perhaps the OP can clarify?

Comment: @ötarcan: Why are you changing this question into something completely different? Even more, since this question already exists as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354151. I did a rollback to the original question (which was addressed with the answers).

Answer (score 2):

If you add an extra $0$ to every code word, we will have a linear code, with the same minimum distance. Just adding any digit won't give a linear code in general. I suppose if you start with a basis for the code you can add an arbitrary digit to each basis element and then extend linearly to the other code words, and get better distance properties, in principle.

Comment: +1 Most typically the extended symbol is the overall checksum. In other words, after the extension the sum of the components of all the codewords equals zero. This process is a special case of the one described here, and thus preserves linearity. The same can be seen from the fact that calculation of that checksum is a linear function.

Comment: to specialize the question;the code C has length n,after adding an extra bit we have the extended code C' that satisfies the following condition:the sum of all the squares of n+1 digit is 0.how can we show the linearness of the extended code that we obtain?

Comment: i am so sorry jyrki but i could not understand why this process preserves linearity,can you explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

A typical extension is to add an overall parity check symbol to $C$, meaning that after the extension, the sum of the entries of any codeword in $C'$ equals $0$. This extended code $C'$ is indeed linear (since the extension rule is linear).

If you just add random symbols, in general $C'$ is not linear.

In general, the extended code C′ is linear if and only if the map $C\to\mathbb F_ q$, mapping a codeword to its extension symbol is linear.

Comment: azimut,do you mean C' is linear if q is even?

Comment: @ötarcan: It depends on the selection rule of the extension symbol, as I wrote.

Comment: sorry azimut i could not understand the linearity of the extension rule that was given in the question.which conditions satisfy the linearity of the extended code C'?